# Which is correct? A book by publisher XYZ, or a book from publisher XYZ?

Tags: prepositions

> I want to talk about a book from XYZ publisher.

or

> I want to talk about a book by XYZ publisher.

or maybe they both wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is subtle.

> A book by X

is what is usually said to convey that X wrote the book. So

> A book by publisher Y

is not idiomatic because it conflicts with the expectation that “book by” is going to name the author.

What is idiomatic is

> A book from publisher Y

This is true even though it is idiomatic to say

> A book published by Y

Here there is no conflict because the word “published” creates the proper expectation for interpreting “by.”